# How to attach a relay or any circuit to make a solar inverter work as UPS

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, ups, solar-charge-controller

I just purchased a new 2.5kW solar inverter. It has following out put functions

When solar power is available it will give AC power from it if solar power is low it will get power from battery and fulfill the load requirement and it will not use the main government supplied electricity.
How can make it work in a way that first when solar is available it will use it and may use battery to cover load but when Sun goes away house can be powered by government supplied electricity and when this electricity goes off battery can give backup. Any diagram for relay implementation or any circuit module that can be used to make this happen?
Inverter has only following options in its settings[image: Inverter User Manual]

Comment: It is not clear what functions the solar power inverter has, but is seems that it has most of the desired functions. To add functions, you must understand the design of the product an be able to make what could be rather complicated modifications. You should probably return the product and buy something that provides everything that you need.

Comment: I am in discussion with seller, if they do not accept the return I may have to add something to get best out of it. The thing is, Inverter uses solar and battery at first priority which leave me no backup when solar goes off and by Main electric supply also goes away due to load shedding in our area.

Comment: Unless the inverter is designed to do so the inverter will not supply the load when the utility power us absent. This arrangement is NOT specifically covered in the options chart that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a utility fed battery charger.

The inverter will draw off battery,unbeknownst that the battery charger is filling it right back up from utility.  That’s how it should be set up anyway.

The product config is stupid,and I wonder if it’s a misprint in the manual.  Most normal people will want the config you want.  I would check with the factory.